# PHP and postgres SQL with placeholders?

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have read a lot of PHP sql examples that use MySQL. I often see queries like this that have placeholders for values:

```php
$query = “INSERT INTO users
(username, firstname, lastname, salutation, countrycode)
VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)”;
```

Notice the values are `:1`, `:2` etc.

I use the standard PHP module for postgres in PHP. My queries inject variables names like this:

```php
$query = “INSERT INTO users(username)
VALUES($hello)”;
```

How do I use the same placebolder technique with postgres in PHP? Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html

Comment: Native PostgreSQL extension ~ https://www.php.net/manual/function.pg-prepare.php. PDO ~ https://www.php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you @Phil, I believe this is what I was looking for.

Comment: For one time queries in a script, I usually use pg_query_params()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared queries cause two database communication roundtrips instead of one: one for prepare, one for execute. If you want to reuse the same query many times, yet only parse it once, they will be faster, but if you want to use the query once, they will be slower. Basically, prepared queries are the wrong answer to your problem ; the correct answer is [parameterized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) queries.

```
$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, 
          'SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = $1 AND last_name=$2', 
          array($firstname,$lastname));
```

This pg-specific function makes a parameterized query where placeholders of the form $number are replaced by the parameters with the corresponding one-based index in the array. Parameters are properly handled, and there is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: I see. I have been using pg_query(), this is much better. Thanks Bobflux